# how to pass props on the view to a redux connected react component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

i have a component called Paginate who recive states from redux and i want to pass a prop normaly on the view to change his comportament depends what page a called it, the props never shows up i alredy tryed pass the component to class and doenst work.

code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/paginate-redux-test-tqi5d

```
      <Provider store={store}>

          <div className="row text-center">
            <Paginate mode="search" />
          </div>

          <div className="row text-center">
            <Paginate mode="report" />
          </div>

      </Provider>
```

inside the view.js = undefined

```
      console.log(props.mode);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this https://codesandbox.io/s/paginate-redux-test-694ev

Reason your passed props to `Paginate` component is not appearing is because you are using `mergeProps` while connecting the component. If so you have to explicitly pass the `ownProps`(3rd param of mergeProps function) to the returned object.

https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api/connect.md#mergeprops-stateprops-dispatchprops-ownprops--object